# Is it possible to override routing function when using AJAX out of a twig template

Tags: php, routes, twig

I am building up a skeleton app with Cartalyst\Sentinel and Twig, where my example is here: https://www.sitepoint.com/removing-the-pain-of-user-authorization-with-sentinel/. I just updated the dependencies, but the principle is the same.

In my twig template I tried to add an XHR-Call with jQuery:

```
{% for user in users %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $("#changeRole_{{ user.id }}").on('change', function() {
                $.post( "../application/ajax/changeUserRole.php", { userId: {{ user.id }}, roleId: this.value })
                    .done(function( msg ) {
                        alert( msg );
                    }
                );
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is that the router tries to resolve the filepath "../application/ajax/changeUserRole.php". So my question is how to avoid that? Maybe there is also a way to define additional XHR-Routes in my router.php.

Let´s have a look at my router.php (this is how I use to define a route):

```
$app->get('/login', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $view = Twig::fromRequest($request);
    $view->render($response, 'login.html.twig');
    return $response;
});
```

Comment: URLs are resolved according to HTTP rules, plain and simple. Anything you do in AJAX will get translated as an HTTP request. Can’t you just define a normal route and use it in AJAX?

Comment: ^This or post your htaccess

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple. I have to use an url like "/admin/users/changeUserRole" and not the filepath like "../application/ajax/changeUserRole.php".

```
{% for user in users %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $("#changeRole_{{ user.id }}").on('change', function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/admin/users/changeUserRole",
                    data: { userId: {{ user.id }}, roleId: this.value },
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert('Error : ' + errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endfor %}
```

after that this works:

```
$app->post('/admin/users/changeUserRole', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $data = $request->getParsedBody();
    
    if (!$data || empty($data)) {
        return $response;
    }
    
    $loggedUser = Sentinel::check();
    
    if ($loggedUser && $loggedUser->hasAccess('user.update')) {

    } else {

    }

    return $response;
});
```